# Datetime components as grouping variables in multi-level model

Tags: repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, time-varying-covariate

Does it make sense to use datetime components (e.g. year, month, day) as grouping variables in a multi-level model?

For example, I have some data that consists of repeated measures within group:

```
group |       date | measurement
------|------------|------------
    1 | 2015-05-01 |   0.5741408
    1 | 2015-05-02 |   0.5486846
    1 | 2015-05-03 |   0.3509362
    : |          : |           :
  483 | 2016-12-24 |   0.8088201
```

I was initially converting the date column so that it was simply the number of days greater than the minimum.

```
mod = lmer(measurement ~ days + (1 | group), data=DF)
```

However I don't necessarily expect a linear time effect and am wondering if I can convert the date column into year, month, and day columns.

```
mod2 = lmer(measurement ~ (1 | group) + (1 | year) + (1 | month) + (1 | day), data=DF)
```

I get a bit confused thinking about the nesting structure of this and am not sure if it is a correct way to model the data. The date column inherently contains a lot of contextual information and I want to be able to leverage that in my model.

Does it create any problems to use the date time components as grouping variables?